# Web Element Randomly stops working

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am using `Selenium WebDriver` for `Visual Studio 2015`. I have had an ongoing problem with a radio button that was originally working and then stops working, then resumes working again. I have tried to narrow down any reason for the cause but I can't seem to isolate the issue.

1. I have tried this on both `IE 10/11` and `Chrome` and neither see the `WebElement` any longer.
2. I have added a Wait Function to try to see if the Element is visible (even tried a sleep just in case)
3. Since it is a `Click()` method i have tried both the click and the sendkeys.enter
4. Multiple paths, by name, css, ID, xpath but the webelement has not changed at all

Please see my code below :-

```
test.Log(LogStatus.Info, "Blah", "Before");
try 
{
    radBtnCID=wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("someID")));
    if (radBtnCID == null)
    {
        test.Log(LogStatus.Error, method, "Web Element Returned Null: radBtnCID");
    }
    else
    {
         radBtnCID.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
         test.Log(LogStatus.Info, radBtnCID.Text, radBtnCID.Text);  
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    test.Log(LogStatus.Error, method, ex.Message);
}
test.Log(LogStatus.Info, "Blah", "After");
```

When I debug the code  after the wait function it moves on to the else statement so its not seeing the `WebElement` as `null`, I have literally watched it execute the line of code but it never does select the desired radio button.It throws no exception and I am successfully seeing my before and after messages. Please help as this has been on going and I am running out of ideas.

Comment: and what is the problem with this `radBtnCID.Click()`??

Comment: Same as with the radBtnCID.SendKeys(Keys.Enter) it looks right at the code and never selected the desired radio button

Comment: Try once using `IJavascriptExecutor` as ==> `IJavascriptExecutor js = driver as IJavascriptExecutor; js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()",radBtnCID);` and let me know..:)

Comment: That did it!! Thank you         IJavaScriptExecutor js = ts.getDriver() as IJavaScriptExecutor;
                    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", radBtnCID);    So does that man there is a Javascript issue with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems designing issue in your page that's why you are unable to perform `IWebElement.Click()` here, You can also try as an alternate solution using `IJavaScriptExecutor` as below :-

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; 
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()",radBtnCID);
```

Comment: The JavaScript injection `HTMLElement.click()` shouldn't be used in a testing context. It defeats the purpose of the test. First because it doesn't generate all the events like a real click (focus, blur, mousedown, mouseup...) and second because it doesn't guarantee that a real user can interact with the element.

Comment: @FlorentB. yes, you are absolutely right, that's why I have mentioned can be use as alternate solution. Thanks to point it out..:)

Comment: @FlorentB. Good point. However, do you have any solution to suggest?

Comment: @Thibstars May be another solution using `Actions` as `Actions.MoveToElement(radBtnCID).Click().Perform()` work here..

Comment: And it's also possible to simulate mouse event using `IJavaScriptExecutor` as `js.executeScript("var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');clickEvent.initEvent('click', true, true); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);", radBtnCID);`..and other events such as `mouseover`,`mouseup`,`mousedown` etc..

Comment: @Andy Williams, you first need to figure out why your code is failing. It's hard to say without a reproducible example. It could be due to a timing issue, or because you are targeting the wrong element. It could also be that you need to perform another action for the element become visible.

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, yes you can also the inject events, but there's no point since the Selenium method `WebElement::Click` is already doing it.

Comment: @Florent B. But is it possible we locate wrong element while JavaScript perform click on right element??

Comment: @Florent B. Yes, I know `WebElement::Click` is already doing it, but what we can do if everything is right but still `WebElement::Click` unable to click??

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur, yes, the click could be performed on the wrong element. Have a look at event bubbling and propagation. You shouldn't assume that the code is right without knowing the behavior of the page. There's a reason the click is failing. It's either a bug in the driver or an an incorrect usage, which is more likely.

Comment: @Florent B. Thanks for such great information, I really appreciate it..:)